# combobox select index changed put it in sessions in master page

Tags: asp.net

can u explain what can i do with the combobox of master page i set database names in combobox and i call through child pages
the code is below
Try

```
        sqlConn = New SqlConnection(strConn)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Dim sqlda1 As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlds1 As New DataSet

        sqlQry = "EXEC sp_databases"
        sqlda1 = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQry, sqlConn)
        sqlda1.Fill(sqlds1, "DataBaseList")
        sqlConn.Close()
        Session.Add("dscb", " ")
        Session.Add("dscb", sqlds1.Tables("DataBaseList"))

        Dim IntPCount As Integer

        IntPCount = sqlds1.Tables("DataBaseList").Rows.Count
        'IntPCount = Session("dscb")
        Dim PCol As String
        ' cbDataBaseList.Items.Clear()
        cbDataBaseList.Items.Clear()
        cbDataBaseList.Text = "Select"

        For p = 0 To IntPCount - 1
            PCol = sqlds1.Tables("DataBaseList").Rows(p).Item("DATABASE_NAME").ToString
            If PCol.Length > 5 Then
                If PCol <> "master" Or PCol <> "msdb" Or PCol <> "tempdb" Then
                    Dim strDataBaseName As String = PCol
                    strDataBaseName = strDataBaseName.Remove(4)
                    '*** Add only "Customer's" which got the prefix "CLT_ " ***
                    If strDataBaseName = "CLT_" Then
                        NewPCol = PCol.Replace("CLT_", "")
                        NewPCol.Trim()
                        'cbDataBaseList.Items.Add(NewPCol)
                        cbDataBaseList.Items.Add(NewPCol)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
                Session.Add("CMBID", "")

        'cbDataBaseList.Text = NewPCol.ToString

        sqlds1.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        strex = ex.Message
        'MessageBox.Show(strex, "General form exception message 5.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End If
```

select index changed event

Session("CMBID") = cbDataBaseList.Text

Comment: what is the problem? Are you not getting the session variable in the child pages?

Comment: yes every time the master page loads and text is changed to default "select"

Comment: the session data is not coming into the child pages when ever redirect to anothre page

Comment: The text is changing to default "select", as you are clearing the list with out any condition. Before clearing and setting the default value, you must check if(Session("CMBID") != null) that way you can avoid loosing the value.

Comment: hi but i cant see the output in child page it displays nothing at this time

Comment: its working but i have another doubt whenever user changes the dropdown that item based data are coming into the how it will do and the user must select dropdown before he going to the child page

Comment: Sometimes, may be most of the time, before the master page can finish executing all the code and set the session value, child page will try to display the value. In that case the child page will display the old value or null value if it is first time. So be careful in getting the value only based on session. Try to get the postback value also.

Answer (score 0):

Is the code mentioned above the Page_Load() function for the master page? If yes, then you have to first check

```
// Check if it has already been set.
if(Session("CMBID") != null) 
{
// Now if it is set, get the value
 String cmbid = (String) Session("CMBID");
//Get the post back value of the combo box  also
String cmbval = Request["<your control name>"];
// Make the above code of setting the combo box value as a separate function
FillComboBoxFromDB();
etif(!cmbval.Equals(cmbid))
{
   // set the session value with the new selected value
   Session("CMBID") = cmbval
 }


}
```

Now do the same checking in session and post back value in child pages. I guess it is in the small time difference of executing the code in master page that the child page is trying to access the session variable before it is set. So just check the session and post back to be double sure.